# Are bias and variance concepts related to a single prediction model or a group of models?

Tags: variance, bias

In bias and variance decomposition theorem, bias and variance are all related to distribution, which means they should be related to a group of models. But people always say this model is high bias or high variance, which makes me very confused. Kindly share me some thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one model. Defining its complete distribution is generally very hard if not impossible, and even its domain space can be hard to figure, mostly in the case of non parametric models like many typically used in ML, but since training data is random, the model trained on it will be random too.

You may find useful [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/433972/what-is-the-random-variable-when-we-talk-about-high-variance-model-or-high-bias).

In the end, what you are interested in is just bias and variance, and, more often than not, just in a theoretical way: you don't have to really measure them, you just have to understand that some models are too sensible to data fluctuations (high variance models), while others are stuck too far from the target (high bias models). The target here is the "perfect model", that predicts everything as well as possible, and you need a bit of bias and a bit of variance to stay as close as possible to it.

By the way, this also applies to unsupervised models were there are no predictions.

Comment: Thx, Carlo. It is a good explanation.

Comment: you are welcome. you can accept the answer then

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That green tick, right? I clicked it.

Comment: yeah, thank you. I hate things left halfway